# Disable _Exit event when quitting userform using "Cancel" or "X-button"

Tags: vba, events, messagebox

I've got a code in a dropdown box on my userform. Every time the user moves away from the drop down box, the code checks whether the value put by the user is correct (i.e. matches a list). If it doesn't, it triggers a message box. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CmboxModifyRoute_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

UserValue = CmboxModifyRoute.Value
counter = 0
Cell = Range("C15").Value

If UserValue = "" Then Exit Sub

Do While (counter < 35 And Cell <> UserValue) 'checking if UserValue is valid
    counter = counter + 1
    Cell = Range("C15").Offset(counter, 0).Value
Loop

If counter > 34 Then 'if invalid, then display message box
    MsgBox "Invalid", vbExclamation
End If

End Sub
```

The problem occurs when I quit the userform with the "X" button or "Cancel" button. If the UserValue is invalid, it still shows me the "Invalid" message box after I have already quit the userform. I don't want it, I just want the userform to unload. How can I deal with this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your condition to this:

```
If Me.Visible And counter > 34 Then 
    MsgBox "Invalid", vbExclamation
End If
```

Then the message will not be displayed if the form isn't visible.

Answer (score 3):

Data Validation should go in the `BeforeUpdate` event of the combo box. Before Update won't trigger prior to the User Form's `Terminate` event. Add `UserForm_Terminate` and `CmboxModifyRoute_BeforeUpdate` events to your code, set breakpoints on the declaration of each, and watch the order of events happen in debug mode.

```
Private Sub CmboxModifyRoute_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'data validation goes here
    'doesn't fire when the form is closed
End Sub

Private Sub CmboxModifyRoute_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'this triggers before Terminate
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

End Sub
```